# Schedule job in jenkins after all dependent jobs are complete at a particular time

Tags: jenkins, automation

I have a requirement where multiple dev builds are present and post their completion, I need to trigger my pipeline deployment job.

So two important requirements: 
All streams' separate jobs should be complete.
Build should run port a specific time even if all builds are complete say after 9PM.

Please suggest and help on how I can proceed with this. I know i will need to play with Build triggers section in the configuration of my deployment build. but unsure on how I can write my shell script and how i can add here to achieve my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use jenkins pipelines. It is a bit of investment - but much more flexible and maintanable. (plus you get everything as code, instead of wizards)

In the pipeline you could implement your build operations as parallel stages, and afterwards with the [waitUntil](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-waituntil-code-wait-for-condition) keyword you can wait until the current time is X hours.